# How to implement rsa-sha256 in go?

Tags: encryption, go

I'm tryign to implement http-signature in go and starting by implementing rsa-sha256 and I'm nog getting the correct value out. So I'm doing something wrong.

I'm using this example data set https://github.com/joyent/node-http-signature/blob/master/http_signing.md#appendix-a---test-values

Here is my code: [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Peo2QVYswb)

As you can se I get another hashed result than expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would gist.github.com/kylelemons/4980202 help?

Comment: Your program returns a different sign every time is executed (you cannot see that in the playgroud, run it locally). That is because OAEP uses a random padding so every signature is different: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding` . You cannot check this kind of signature by comparing it with another execution when random padding or a random initialization vector is used.